# CakePhp 3.x select contain where row is NULL

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

It's not clear to me how I can fetch records that don't have a reference in an other row using `contain()` in Cakephp

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{        
    $this->hasmany('Prior', [
        'className' => 'Prior',
        'foreignKey' => 'photoID'
    ]);
}

public function search()
{
    $query = $this->find('all')->contain(['Prior']);
    return $query;
}
```

This returns something like:

```
-> results
  ->0
     ->ID = 1
     ->Prior = null

  ->1
     ->ID = 2
     ->Prior = array()

  ->2
     ->ID = 3
     ->Prior = array()

  ->3
     ->ID = 4
     ->Prior = null
```

How can I return only the `NULL` results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `notMatching` (see the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching))

```
$this->find('all')
    ->contain(['Prior'])
    ->notMatching('Prior');
```